# Tag edits result in a "success" screen instead of the updated post

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, edits, inline-tag-editor

When editing a post's tags today (directly, via the "Edit tags" link), the tag edits are successful, but instead of returning me to an updated page, I receive something like:

```
{"success":true,"html":"<a href=\"/questions/tagged/linux\" class=\"post-tag\" title=\"show questions tagged &#39;linux&#39;\" rel=\"tag\">linux</a>< ... continues ...
```

This happened to me on U&L, and terdon has confirmed it also occurs for him on ELU.

Comment: Reproduced on [scifi.se].

Comment: If it matters, the browser is Chrome Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit). I have various extensions installed, but I don't see them interfering at this point.

Comment: Editing via the full "edit" link appears to bypass the issue.

Comment: Reproduced on Chromium Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-bit).

Comment: For reference, I repro'd on Ubuntu 16, Chrome 68, 64-bit.

Comment: SO bug report: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377497/editing-tags-with-edit-tags-in-a-question-redirects-me-to-showing-code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A crucial line of code was inadvertently removed from the script that handles the results of edits... This led to a script error, which in turn prevented the script from stopping the default behavior for a submit button. So you got redirected to the editor submission route instead of seeing the results rendered inline.

I've re-added the omitted line, and all seems to be well again. Sorry for the inconvenience!